# Вместо назначенной картинки показывается другая

Tags: html, css, html5

Проблема при верстке шаблона.Я поставил кнопки на слайдер. С правой стороны кнопки отображаются корректно, слева кнопки почему то другие. В исходном коде сайта можно найти ссылку на изображение кнопки. Вот эта кнопка, если зайти по прямой ссылке:

[Кнопка влево](http://plus.iseeweb.ru/images/icons/mn-arr-l.svg)

Однако на самом сайте отображается совсем другая. Я думал что проблема в кэше, но это не так, так как пробовал уже разные браузеры и чистил все. Кто может помочь разобраться? [Вот страница](http://plus.iseeweb.ru/#) на которой видно проблему.

Comment: width:35px поставьте вместо 21px

Comment: вот я дурак) спасибо точно) она же обрезается из-за длинны)

Comment: Слоган при обнаружении проблемы))